# How to change the appearance of navigation menu when javascript disabled.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am re-building a website with a navigation menu that uses javascript, but when javascript is disabled the sub menu's list stack below.  Is there anyway I make then disappear or change their colour to white so to blend in with the body background colour when the javascript is disabled?

I have this problem with a carousel, a content slider also and jquery tabs.  When I used to use Easy Slider I gave the list's individual id's and then in the css markup put the display to none and this worked, but it doesn't with any of these.

Navigation menu I am using is http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/examples/

The content slider - 
http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/featured-content-slider-using-jquery-ui/

I've read an article about graceful degrading, but i don't really understand.  Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Use CSS. SO is for answering questions about specific problems, not writing all your code for you. read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Is there a reason why giving individual lists a display of none would work with one jquery application but not another?  After all they are both based on lists.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `noscript` tag to add style rules to the page that will hide those elements (e.g., given them `display: none`), like so:

```
<noscript>
<style>
relevantSelector {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</noscript>
```

The content in a `noscript` tag is only included if the browser doesn't have JavaScript or JavaScript is turned off. You could also use this technique to reveal non-JavaScript navigational elements.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("slide2").style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById("slide3").style.display =  "block";
          $(document).ready(function(){ 
             $("#slider").easySlider({
                  auto: true, 
                  continuous: true
                  });
              }); 
         </script> This was the code I used on easy slider and gave slide 2 and 3 a display: none in the css, and this was great, the first image of the slider was visible when javascript was disabled, but it doesn't work on the other plugins.

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder.  It works for the javascript navigation menu.  I read that the no script doesn't work for javascript that has been disabled by firewalls.  IF I put this code at the bottom of the document would this work - ?     <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("noscript").style.display = "none"; 
      </script>